# Why my HTML Email is losing styles when sent via Node.js?

Tags: html, node.js, email

I am trying to send a HTML email using Node.js.

The HTML code you are gonna see below is designed via **MailChimp**. I exported it as an HTML. I sent a test email to GMail via mailchip and it looks so nice and it is just as how it is designed in Mailchimp.

However when I exported this and send it via my code, all styles are lost. I will show you an email sent by mailchip and an email sent by my code, there will be screenshots down there.

My question is, what am I missing here? How to fix this?

****send-email.js****

```
/**
 * Send emails using this method
 * 
 */
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');
const errorCodes = require('source/error-codes');
const emailTemplates = require('source/email/email-templates');
const PropertiesReader = require('properties-reader');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const prop = PropertiesReader('properties.properties');

const pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 10,
    host: prop.get('server.host'),
    user: prop.get("server.username"),
    password: prop.get("server.password"),
    port: prop.get("server.port"),
    database: prop.get("server.dbname")
});


exports.sendEmail = async (event, context) => {

    const connection = await pool.getConnection();

    if (event.body == null && event.body == undefined) {
        return errorCodes.missing_parameters;
    }

    let body = JSON.parse(event.body);

    if (body.emailType == null || body.emailType.length == 0) {
        console.log(errorResponse);
        return errorCodes.createErrorResponse(401, "emailType cannot be empty");
    }

    if (body.emailType !== "MEETING_INVITE") {
        console.log(errorResponse);
        return errorCodes.createErrorResponse(401, "invalid emailType");
    }


    // Validations passed. Proceed
    const emailType = body.emailType;

    try {
        await connection.beginTransaction();
        let emailTemplate = "";

        //
        //Meeting invite email
        //
        if (emailType == "MEETING_INVITE") {

            emailTemplate = await getMeetingEmail();
            console.log(emailTemplate);
        }

        AWS.config.update({
            region: 'us-east-1'
        });

        const ses = new AWS.SES();

        const emailParams = {
            Destination: {
                ToAddresses: ["abcd@gmail.com"],
            },
            Message: {
                Body: {
                    Html: {
                        Charset: "UTF-8",
                        Data: emailTemplate,
                    },
                },
                Subject: {
                    Charset: "UTF-8",
                    Data: "abcd | You are invited for a video meeting",
                },
            },
            Source: "abcd Technologies Inc. <no-reply@abcd.com>",
        };

        const {
            MessageId
        } = await ses.sendEmail(emailParams).promise();
        console.log('Email sent:', MessageId);



    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return errorCodes.internal_server_error;
    } finally {
        connection.release();
    }

    /**
     * meeting invite function
     * */
    async function getMeetingEmail() {
        if (body.senderId == null ||
            body.recieverId == null ||
            body.startTime == null ||
            body.meetingId == null || body.meetingId.length == 0 ||
            body.endTime == null) {
            return errorCodes.not_null_parameters;
        }

        if (isNaN(body.senderId) || isNaN(body.recieverId)) {
            return errorCodes.missing_fields;
        }

        const senderId = body.senderId;
        const recieverId = body.recieverId;
        const startTime = new Date(body.startTime);
        const endTime = new Date(body.endTime);
        const meetingId = body.meetingId;
        let senderName = "";
        let recieverName = "";
        let recieverEmail = "";

        const options = {
            year: 'numeric',
            month: '2-digit',
            day: '2-digit',
            hour: '2-digit',
            minute: '2-digit',
            hour12: true
        };

        const formattedStartTime = startTime.toLocaleString('en-US', options).replace(',', ' at');
        console.log(formattedStartTime);

        const formattedEndTime = endTime.toLocaleString('en-US', options).replace(',', ' at');
        console.log(formattedEndTime);

        //get the information of the sender
        const senderDataSql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE iduser = ?";
        const [senderData, senderMeta] = await connection.query(senderDataSql, [senderId]);

        senderName = senderData[0].first_name;

        //get the information of the reciever
        const recieverDataSql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE iduser = ?";
        const [recieverData, recieverMeta] = await connection.query(recieverDataSql, [recieverId]);

        recieverName = recieverData[0].first_name;
        recieverEmail = recieverData[0].email;

        //get the email template
        return emailTemplates.getMeetingEmail(senderName, recieverName, formattedStartTime, formattedEndTime, meetingId);

        //send the email
        //wait meetingEmail(senderName, recieverName, recieverEmail, formattedStartTime, formattedEndTime, meetingId);

    }
}
```

**email-templates.js**

This code is too lengthy to be posted here. So, I have posted that in Pastebin. Here is the link - https://pastebin.com/mfh12DR4

Email sent by mailchimp

[image]

Email sent by my code

[image]